# In-App Purchases restore button necessary?

Tags: in-app-purchase, restore

guys I've implemented an in-app purchase using PARSE. Now there is no restore button in my app . My DB, hosted on the PARSE cloud has a an attribute called "hasMadePurchase" in my User's table which is checked every time the user tries to make a purchase. The attribute is set to yes as soon as a successful purchase has been made.

Now with that, do I need a restore purchases button for the app to get it through the app store? Cause clearly, even if the user changes his/her device deletes and re-installs the app or whatever he/she will still be able to get all his/her purchases back.

If yes, than what do I need to implement in my restore function? (which would basically do nothing, other than making fake calls, i don't know i am kinda lost)

Answer (score 0):

A restore purchases button is needed only if the app offers non-consumable IAPs, e.g. unlocking content. Our game got rejected recently exactly for this reason - we were offering weapon unlocks and we were missing the restore purchases button.

If you are offering non-consumable IAPs then you can start by looking into [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions] and go from there. Basically, this fetches the list of all IAP SKUs that have been previously purchased by the user.

Comment: can you give me some code to put under my restore button? which would basically do nothing apart from pulling what the user have purchased.

Comment: Indeed, another example of an app being rejected for not implementing the restore feature is here: http://matt.coneybeare.me/app-store-rejection-for-not-having-in-app-purchase-restoration/
Even though it doesn't make sense for a lot of apps to have a restore button, it seems like Apple doesn't give us a choice.